# How to get a Cursor in sqlite db to work?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Ive made a user register activity and it succesfully adds the user details to the database but now I am trying to get the user to be able to login with the same details but I have ran into a problem where I have a error in the code below saying comma or semi column needed but I dont think thats the correct answer to my problem. Can anyone see why my error would be happening? The error is where it says "SELECT * FROM" the from is the error and "WHERE" is the other error.

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    openHelper = new DatabaseHelperUser(this);
    db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    final EditText userEdit = findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    final EditText passwordEdit = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
    final Button loginBt = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    loginBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


           String userEt = userEdit.getText().toString();
           String userP = passwordEdit.getText().toString();


          cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseHelperUser.TABLE_NAME + "WHERE" + DatabaseHelperUser.COL2 + "=? AND" + DatabaseHelperUser.COL3 + "=?", new String[]{userEt, userP});
```

DatabaseHelperUser class:

```
public class DatabaseHelperUser extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "User_table";
public static final String COL1 = "UserNum";
public static final String COL2 = "UserName";
public static final String COL3 = "Password";
public static final String COL4 = "BirthDate";
public static final String COL5 = "Phone";
public static final String COL6 = "Address";


public  DatabaseHelperUser(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (UserNum TEXT,UserName Text,Password Text,BirthDate Text,Phone Text,Address Text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add space to command `FROM` , `WHERE`, `AND` :

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelperUser.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelperUser.COL2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelperUser.COL3 + "=?", new String[]{userEt, userP});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please include the full text of the error in your question, but it looks to me like:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + DatabaseHelperUser.TABLE_NAME
                            + "WHERE" + DatabaseHelperUser.COL2 +
                           "=? AND" + DatabaseHelperUser.COL3 + "=?", 
                           new String[]{userEt, userP});
```

I see that there is no trailing space after `FROM`, `WHERE` and `AND`, and since your `TABLE_NAME` etc does not have a leading space, `FROMUser_tableWHEREUserName` is going to be a syntax error.

Comment: Yes I see! I have now added a space after FROM and WHERE and its working now thank you